# Why does $\int_{0}^{1}x^1\,dx=\frac{1}{2}$, and $\int_{0}^{1}x^2\,dx=\frac{1}{3}$, and $\int_{0}^{1}x^3\,dx=\frac{1}{4}$, and so on?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The $\int_{0}^{1}x^a\,dx$ seems to equal $\frac{1}{a+1}$. I just came across this and thought it must be known why this is.

See the the table below:
[image: Desmos Graph]

Why are these nice fractions showing up out of nowhere; what does the area under $F(x)=x^a$ between $x=0$ and $x=1$ have to do with these nice fractions?

Of course, the antiderivative of $x^a$ is $\frac{{x}^{a+1}}{a+1}$. And, that evaluated from $0$ to $1$ is just $\frac{{1}^{a+1}}{a+1}$, which equals $\frac{1}{a+1}$.

**But what is the geometrical link here, between this integral and these nice fractions?**

Comment: Can I ask, how much calculus do you know? Do you know about the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: Here's an extremely related fact: the area of a triangle is 1/2 base times height. The volume of a pyramid is 1/3 base times height. In the fourth dimension, we say the "hypervolume" of a "4-simplex" (aka a "5-cell") is 1/4 base times height.

Comment: I am a Calculus 2 student.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps you ,https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8nak6fm0ks

[image]

you can Imagine $y=\frac 1{x+1} \ \forall x=n\in \mathbb{N}$ and cross-section of $y=\frac 1{x+1}$ and integral $[0,1]$
[image]

Te second desmos file is https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vy5ybvxejp

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question is a good question.

Yes you are correct. That is :

$\int_{0}^{1}xdx=\frac{1}{2},\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}dx=\frac{1}{3},...$

This is generally the formula of induction. That is we know that $\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}dx=\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: Since I am a class XIITh student so I have only this much idea. Might be my answer is wrong.